# Getting error "Call to undefined function wkhtmltox_convert()" in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I am getting this error and am unable to find a solution.

I am able generate PDF from commandline.

I am on a shared server so may not have many options.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you including the appropriate files? Crystal ball is a little fuzzy right now.

Comment: Did you install the php bindings for wkhtmltox? https://github.com/mreiferson/php-wkhtmltox

Comment: I tried installing php bindings - I get this error: %phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/local/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

Answer (score 0):

You need install wkhtmltox module as php in your web-servewr